# Search products using taxon_id in SpreeCommerce API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, spree

I am trying to search products from the SpreeCommerce API using `taxon_ids` as the filter. [The search api](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/products.html#search) uses the ransack gem [predicates](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) for searching. I have tried:

```
/api/products?q[taxon_ids_cont]=x
```

(where x is an id of a taxon ). I have also tried:

```
/api/products?q[taxon_ids_in]=x
```

and both return a json of all products without filtering. What parameters should I use on the `products` endpoint to fetch products filtered by `taxon_ids` or How else can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Found a solution. SpreeCommerce API has an action named `products` in the taxons controller which can be accessed via `/api/taxons/products` endpoint.

```
def products
    # Returns the products sorted by their position with the classification
    # Products#index does not do the sorting.
    taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:id])
    @products = taxon.products.ransack(params[:q]).result
    @products = @products.page(params[:page]).per(500 || params[:per_page])
    render "spree/api/products/index"
  end
```

The endpoint takes a parameter `id` and optionally takes a `:q` parameter which is [a ransack gem predicate](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching)

for example the url:

```
/api/taxons/products?id=1
```

will return a json of all products under the taxon with an `id` of 1

```
/api/taxons/products?id=1&q[name_cont]=Bag
```

will return a json of products under the taxon with an id of 1 and their names contains the word Bag. I am not sure why this piece of information is missing on the official API guide.

Comment: Note that this endpoint returns products that have been discontinued (unlike the /api/products endpoint.